# Wingpanel Network Manager (WPA-3) Bug elementary OS 6.1 Jólnir

Tags: wifi, wingpanel, bugs

since WPA-3 is supported, the Connection Manager in Wingpanel looks like below in the attached screenshot:

[image]

one is unable to select the shown networks and needs to manually connect, as otherwise it ask to enter the password. Many unspecified Networks are shown as unsecure, although they are secured networks.

If one goes to Settings > Network > Wireless, the available Networks are shown correctly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your report, but bugs are better posted in https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-network/issues, where they can be fixed.

Comment: thanks! will go there and post it.